# Automatically refresh Leaflet Markers from MySQL

Tags: leaflet, php, mysql

I have a leaflet map that loads marker details from a MySQL database. I have a timer that clears and reloads the layers (and therefore markers); however; it doesn't seem to be refreshing the data. Code below:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([52.474751, 1.753640], 08);
L.tileLayer( 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZmVybmNvbSIsImEiOiJjam96dHY0Y2Myb3liM3FwYWgyM2xhdXN6In0.aiq5NoW5QMJSc0JUrlz_tA', {
  maxZoom: 20,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/"> OpenStreetMap </a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/"> CC-BY-SA </a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
}).addTo(map);

var fernicons = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    iconSize:     [20, 20],
    iconAnchor:   [10, 10],
    popupAnchor:  [0, 0]
  }
});

var aisicon = new fernicons({iconUrl: 'js/images/ais.png'}),
  radioicon = new fernicons({iconUrl: 'js/images/radio.png'});

var markerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map), markerGroup2 = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);  
$( document ).ready(function() {
  addData();
  addRadio();   
  timer();
});

function timer() {
  setInterval(function(){   
    map.removeLayer(markerGroup);
    addData();
    map.removeLayer(markerGroup2);
    addRadio();
  }, 5000)};

function addData() {
  <?php  $alias = $conn->getList();  ?>
  var List = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($alias) ?>' );
  markerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

  for(var i=0; i<List.length; i++) {
    marker = L.marker( [List[i]['lat'], List[i]['lng']], {icon: aisicon}).addTo(markerGroup);
    marker.bindPopup( "<b>" + List[i]['alias']+"</b><br>MMSI:" + List[i]['ident'] + "<br>";
  }
}

function addRadio() {
  <?php  $alias = $conn->getOnline();  ?>
  var List = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($alias) ?>' );
  markerGroup2 = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
  for(var i=0; i<List.length; i++) {
    marker = L.marker( [List[i]['lat'], List[i]['lng']]).addTo(markerGroup2);
    marker.bindPopup( "<b>" + List[i]['alias']+"</b><br>Radio ID:" + List[i]['ident']+ "<br><a href='./edit.php?ident="+ List[i]['ident']+"'target='_blank'>Edit Radio</a>"); 
  }
}
```

Comment: It's suspicious that you are trying to parse a string here, instead of the JSON object returned by php. `var List = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($alias) ?>' );`

Comment: Please also share any relevant error messages that appear in the Console.

Comment: How is `List` going to update on the client side? PHP only evaluates this when the page is served. I think you need to write an endpoint to fetch the data from.

Comment: php header refresh > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383371/refresh-a-page-using-php

Answer (score 1):

```
var List = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($alias) ?>' );
```

This won't update when the timer fires - PHP only evaluates this once when then page is served.

You probably want to write an endpoint that serves the latest data. This could be geojson ([basic example](https://gist.github.com/wboykinm/5730504)) and you could use [L.GeoJson.Ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax). Or you can serve your own format which you parse and create markers.